# TV not seen by Windows PCs

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, tv

If have a TV (LG 47LW5400) from 2011. It refuses to display anything (reports "no signal") if I connect any Windows 10 PC to it over HDMI cable.

- I have tried it with a Laptop, my regular desktop, and a fanless Media PC, all different brands
- with any other non-PC source (tried with Raspberry Pi, FireTV stick, and a satelite receiver), the "problem TV" shows video successfully
- moreover, the PCs work fine with other TVs/Monitors
- I have also tried three different cables of different brands, all around 1m-1.5m long
- the cables also work fine with other device combinations
- I also checked all the usual means of adding/detecting a display in Windows (especially for the laptop, which needs options for a second display), which I consider myself very experienced at; for the laptop, for example, trying to detect a second screen reports something like "no additional displays found"
- I also created custom display configurations with CRU (Custom Resolution Utility), to no avail, because the PC doesn't actually get to the point where it recognizes the TV and says: "hey I know you can only display resolution XY, but I will politely ignore that and supply my own resolution"
- I have also tried different HDMI ports (which also work with other sources...) on the TV, in order to rule out loose connections
- I have also updated the TV to the latest firmware (which I was surprised to find after all these years, because this is not really a smart TV in today's sense)
- every possible setting of the TV that could solve the problem has been checked; the problem definitely cannot be solved with the remote
- googling for all the trivial solutions to HDMI problems ("dumb user problems") has been dutifully handled

I also figured that it is probably not an HDCP issue of the "problem TV", because the "problem TV" works successfully together with a FireTV stick or BluRay player (which I think require HDCP of the TV to work). I am not sure whether the PCs could have an HDCP issue, because they work with other TVs, and furthermore, HDCP as I understand it, is something that the player requires of the display device, not vice-versa.

So, I thought this weird behavior was probably just the consequence of the TV reporting some wrong EDID data, that are incompatible with Windows or the video cards. So I bought an EDID injector. But the TV still shows "no signal" when connected to a Windows PC over the injector.

So, I first checked if the EDID injector was functional at all, by connecting it to another TV. And, yes, it changes resolutions correctly with that other TV. But when I connect it to my "problem TV" again and a working source (a fire TV stick), the resolution does not change at all if I turn the EDID knob on the injector. So the injector is functional, if connected to a sane TV.

Now I am completely puzzled as to what happens there:

1. working sources seem to ignore the EDID data from the injector, but only if they are connected to my problematic TV (which I thought they wouldn't see if I messed with the EDID data...)
2. the (wrong or injected) EDID data do not seem to be the cause of the "no signal" problem, when I connect a PC to that damn TV. Actually, Windows does not seem to be able to detect the presence of the TV at all.

My next idea would be to buy a dummy HDMI stick (like the ones they use for headless computers) and an HDMI splitter, in order to fake a working monitor to the Windows PC, and branch out the video signal to my TV at the same time. But I don't know if this will work.

Is there anyone who has enough insight into HDMI standard/implementation to enlighten me? Any proposals for further troubleshooting?

I don't want to buy tons of HDMI manipulation devices, if they don't work in the end, and, moreover, the costs would quickly pile up to the price of a new TV. And of course, trashing an otherwise completely functional TV would be less than sustainable.

Comment: Is you TV [HDMI ARC](https://www.techinweb.com/what-is-hdmi-arc/) compatible?

Comment: @Toto: No... No inputs labeled "ARC". Nothing mentioned in the manual. Nothing found in the settings.

Comment: If the TV has an OSD configuration, check that its values make sense for Windows. This includes resolution and anything else that's configurable.

Comment: @harrymc: thanks, that is another thing I forgot to mention among the list of things I have already tried (actually one of the first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved the problem, albeit in a pretty unexpected way.

I bought an HDMI splitter for simultaneous display ([this one](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07KKMQWML/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00) worked for me, but I do not want to advertise it, there are probably lots of others that work equally well).

My original intention was to plug my "problem TV" and an HDMI dummy plug into the splitter at the same time, so that the dummy reports correct EDID/resolutions to the PC, and the TV has to just accept what it gets served.

But to my surprise, the PC already supplied a working signal through the splitter to the TV, if only the TV was plugged into it (without the dummy or any other second monitor)!

I don't know what's going on there, but I am glad it works now with my cherished old TV.